# DaVinci Resolve 16 the content of all videos become black

Tags: davinci-resolve

[image]

I used to be able to see the content of all videos, but since today they all turned into black screen.

Googled and found a few posts
e.g. [DaVinci Resolve 16 shows black screen on imported media](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/28035/davinci-resolve-16-shows-black-screen-on-imported-media)
After 1 year 4 months there is still not a working answer.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04, with NVIDIA RTX 2080Ti and Driver 450 installed
[image]

Comment: What do the properties display?